# bootstrap responsive utilities working - but there is a viewport gap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visibility, responsive

I'm trying to show a long banner at at every veiwport except xs, and then swap it out for a shorter banner ad at xs.

Using bootstrap responsive utility classes, I've been able to do so - to a point. There is a screen size gamut of 321px-767px where the larger ad disappears and the smaller one appears. I want this to still showcase the longer ad, but it only shows the smaller one.

I've tried all sorts of combinations, including .hidden classes, but still can't get it to work for that one particular gap size.

Here is my code:

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for the delay in my response!

Seems like my code was deleted somehow(?). At any rate, I can't recall what I eventualy ended up doing, but some of my problems were with Word Press which was somehow screwing things up. Sometimes the classes worked, then other times they didn't. it's been hit and miss.

Bootstrap hidden and visible classes don't cover all the breakpoints, I'm learning (and I am indeed still learning). So I would have to do media queries in some instances.

Anyway, thought I'd update and again - sorry for not responding sooner!

B.